# Estoy intentando que cuando se completen las posiciones del array[] no me deje insertar mas registros

Tags: java

Cada vez que llamo al metodo me reinicia el contador a cero pero tengo que declarar la variable. En la clase que  contiene este metodo declare el atributo:

```
private Vehiculo[] listaVehiculos;
```

y construí el objeto

```
 public Parking() {//C
    listaVehiculos= new Vehiculo[8];
   }
```

.

```
private void insertarCocheArray(Scanner in) {
    int plaza,opcion,contador,libres = 0;   //A
    String nombre;
    boolean lleno= false;
    contador=0;
    while (contador != 8) {


        if (contador==listaVehiculos.length) {

            lleno=true;
        }
        if (lleno) {
            System.out.println("lleno");
        }else {


            System.out.println("Tenemos un garage con "+listaVehiculos.length+" plazas.");//aun estan todas desocupadas


            do {
                System.out.println("Elige en que plaza vas a guardar el coche 1/8 "); 
                plaza=in.nextInt();
            } while (plaza<1 || plaza >8);


            if (listaVehiculos[plaza-1]==null) {
                System.out.println("La plaza "+plaza+" esta disponible");
                System.out.println("Introduce el modelo");
                nombre=in.next();
                listaVehiculos[plaza-1]=new Vehiculo(nombre);
                contador++;

                System.out.println("Seha guardado el "+listaVehiculos[plaza-1]+" en la plaza "+plaza);

            }else {
                System.out.println("La plaza "+plaza+" no esta disponible por que la ocupa el "+listaVehiculos[plaza-1]);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: La variable `contador` debes definirla como un atributo de la clase y no como una variable dentro del método.

Comment: Me ha valido gracias.

Comment: Estaría bien añadir una respuesta, para hacer ver que está solucionado. ;)

Comment: Tenia la clase Parking  con un metodo para añadir coches a un array ese metodo tenia declarado un contador a 0 y cada vez que llamaba al metodo para insertar un coche contador volvia a cero. Al declarar  contador como atributo de la clase parking cada vez que llamaba al metodo no se volvia ainiciar a cero y al llegar al limite del array no me dejaba insertar mas datos.